# ComboBox causes the whole frame to stop drawing when using

Tags: c, winapi

A problem occured when using ComboBox. When I press the ComboBox, the whole Window frame stops drawing and kinda freezes. I can still press other controls or the X-Button, but nothing is getting rendered.

It starts rendering again when I lose focus of the whole window.

Here is the exact source code I tried (excluding the main function wrapping around all and the include of windows.h):

```
WNDCLASS wc = {};
wc.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszClassName = "CustomWindowClass";
wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
RegisterClass(&wc);

HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

HWND hWnd = CreateWindow("CustomWindowClass", "Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
if(hWnd == NULL)
    return 1;

CreateWindow("ComboBox", NULL, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 100, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);

MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

I have no idea what to try to fix this or how to fix this. I just tried to search the web for some information, but no luck. I am using Windows 7. Other controls work fine.

My question is simply: What could cause this?

Comment: You are using `hWnd` in `GetMessage`. Just put `0` or `NULL` instead.

Comment: @DanielSęk You found the cause, thanks. But why did it not work when having `hWnd` passed into the function?

Comment: Because that parameter is a filter. When passing in the handle of a window, you aren't receiving any messages for child windows, for example. [Psychic debugging: Why messages aren't getting processed by your message pump](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140117-00/?p=2053).